# How should one get the indices of list duplicate elements where the elements are lists?

Tags: python, list, recursion, duplicates

I can define a function that returns the indices of duplicate elements in a list:

```
>>> def indices_of_list_element_duplicates(x):
...     seen = set()
...     seen_add = seen.add
...     return [index for index, element in enumerate(x)\
...         if element in seen or seen_add(element)]
...
```

This function works well for simple lists:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3]
>>> indices_of_list_element_duplicates(a)
[3, 5]
```

How could I change this function to get it to work on lists that have lists as elements?

```
>>> b = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, "d"], [3, "d"], [4, 4], [3, "d"]]
>>> indices_of_list_element_duplicates(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in indices_of_list_element_duplicates
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: How do you expect it to work on lists of lists? I can basically see three ways. (1.) Works as before on the individual lists inside the outer one, (2.) Works as before but comparing for duplicate _lists_ (as in, `[1,2]` occurs twice), (3.) Works as before but _only_ for nested lists of lists (and not, say, for a regular list of ints).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following generator function that yields the index of the duplicate elements. Note that this will still work with a simple list of ints, list of list or both.

```
>>> def index_of_list_element_duplicates(x):
...     seen = set()
...     for index, element in enumerate(x):
...         if isinstance(element, list):
...             element = tuple(element)
...         if element not in seen:
...             seen.add(element)
...         else:
...             yield index
... 
>>> b = [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 'd'], [3, 'd'], [4, 4], [3, 'd'], 4, 4]
>>> list(index_of_list_element_duplicates(b))
[3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

List objects are not hashable so you can not store them in a `set`, you can convert them to tuple which are hashable.

Also as a more pythonic way for finding the duplicate items you better to use a dictionary to preserve the items as the key and indices and indices in a list as value.

```
>>> Counter_obj={}
>>> 
>>> for i,j in enumerate(map(tuple,b)):
...     Counter_obj.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
... 
>>> Counter_obj
{(3, 'd'): [2, 3, 5], (4, 4): [4], (1, 1): [0], (2, 2): [1]}
```

And then you can use a nested list comprehension return the values (indices) with length more than 2:

```
>>> [i for val in Counter_obj.values() for i in val if  len(val)>2]
[2, 3, 5]
```

And if you want to use this in a function as a more general way you can use following approach to wrap both cases :

```
def indices_of_list_element_duplicates(x,Counter_obj={}):
     try:
        for i,j in enumerate(map(tuple,b)):
            Counter_obj.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
     except TypeError:
        for i,j in enumerate(b):
            Counter_obj.setdefault(j,[]).append(i)
     return [i for val in Counter_obj.values() for i in val if len(val)>2]
```

Comment: Not sure if this matters to OP, but converting all list members to `tuple` breaks the function over its previous domain. That is, it would no longer work on a simple list of ints.